# Как обрабатываются нажатия клавиш в python3 и pyqt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Допустим ввожу я в текстовое поле текст, нажимаю Enter и текст из текстового поля попадает в метку(Label). Нужно сам процесс понять как обрабатываются нажатия клавиш.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 9):

Операционная система постоянно следит за состояние периферийных устройств и посылает программам сообщения о том или ином событии, в зависимости от разных условий. Далее эти сигналы можно обработать внутри программы.

Программа на PyQt скрывает от Вас весь сложный процесс обработки. В результате Вам надо только знать, что виджеты эти события получают. Так же можно попросить виджет выполнить какую-либо Вашу функцию, если он получил то или иное событие.

В PyQt это называется система сигналов и слотов.

К примеру, вот сигналы(события) которые может [получить QLineEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#signals). Среди них есть сигнал `returnPressed()`. Остается добавить только нашу функцию в слот, что бы PyQt ее вызвал при получении события нажатия Enter и выставил QLabel нужный текст.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QLabel

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(250, 150)
        self.move(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Simple')

        self.le = QLineEdit(self)
        self.le.move(22, 22)
        self.le.returnPressed.connect(self.pressedKeys)

        self.lbl = QLabel(self)
        self.lbl.move(22, 40)
        self.lbl.resize(100,20)

        self.show()

    def pressedKeys(self):
        print(self.le.text())
        self.lbl.setText(self.le.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```